# Adding Labels Between Reference Lines SAS

Tags: sas, label

I know how to add labels to reference lines, but how can I add labels *between* reference lines?

Here is my code right now:

```
 proc sgplot data=biosc.Summary;
 series  x=day y=Mean / group=Treat;
 scatter x=day y=Mean / group=Treat
   yerrorlower=LowerSD yerrorupper=UpperSD;
   where day in (3:10);
 xaxistable N / location=inside class=Treat colorgroup=Treat
          title="Number of Patients Participating by Treatment Day"
          valueattrs=(size=10) labelattrs=(size=10);
 yaxis label='Mean +/- SD';
 xaxis label='Study Day' values=(3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10);
 refline 4 8 / axis=x;
 run;
```

**And here is my graph:**

[image]

What I want to do is have a label "Phase 1" to the left of the reference line at 4, "Phase 2" between the 2 reference lines, and "Phase 3" to the right of the reference lines at 4.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them using the [LABEL option](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/grstatproc/n0ezn6n9coszztn100iyzhfvwnhp.htm#n09kmeq6dvjpdwn1krl021aum9kc) on REFLINE statement.

LABEL <=variable> | <=(“text-string-1” ... “text-string-n”)>
creates labels for each reference line. If you do not specify a label value, the reference value for that line is used as the label.
If you specify a label value, the following options are available.

You can use `labelloc` and `labelpos` to help control the location.

```
refline 4 8 / axis=x label = ("Phase 1", "Phase 2") labelloc=inside;
```

If you cannot get them placed exactly where you want, you can specify an X/Y location and use a TEXT statement instead. This does require you to add the data to your graphing data set though.

```
data refLabels;
infile cards dlm=',';
input label_x label_y label_text $;
4, 45, Phase 1
5, 45, Phase 2
;;;;

data biosc.summary1;
set biosc.summary1 refLabels;
run;
```

Then add a [text](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/grstatproc/n0lprj1bdrlrkgn1vmqnd7r6fnry.htm) statement to your SGPLOT.

```
text x = label_x y = label_y text = label_text;
```